# Best UML designing tool in Linux?

Tags: linux, uml

Urgently want to know best UML designing tool in Linux?
Which Also Support ERD 
Is it Possible to use in NetBEANs IDE 6.9.1

Comment: this has been answered on Programmers.SE: [best free uml tool](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11002/best-free-uml-authoring-tool)

Answer (score 2):

Almost all UML tools are Linux compliant. 
Try Papurus with Eclipse or BOUML which are free and open source. RSA is pretty good as well as Omondo but not free.

Answer (score 2):

I use and prefer [Umbrello](http://uml.sourceforge.net/).

[ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) is also quite good but its GUI bugs will drive you mad...

Answer (score 1):

I never had any problems with dia. It's part of gnome, almost all distributions package it. Also has a Windows version but I didn't use that one for a long time. Of course, "best" is relative to what you are expecting from it.